# How to concatenate this string properly?

Tags: java

```
String[] str = {"this", "is", "a", "test", "."}
```

I want to output:

```
"this is a test."

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  sb.append(str[i] + " ");
}
```

However, this will output: "this is a test .". How to properly avoid the space before the dot?

Comment: I think we need a more general rule here. Under what exact circumstances do you not want a space? Only when the next array-element is exactly `"."`?

Comment: suppose we need a general condition like last character does not need a space.

Comment: Yes. a few punctuation marks.

Comment: You need to be more specific. It's not clear when you want spaces and when you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a java developer, but here's the quick & dirty (sorry for any syntax violations)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  if(i==str.length-1 || i==0){
    sb.append(str[i]);
  }else{
    sb.append(" "+str[i]);
  }
}
```

For the first or the last item, just add the value to the string, otherwise add a space and the value.

Comment: Something like this is best.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the space before the last character after concat operation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = {"this", "is", "a", "test", "."};

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        sb.append(str[i] + " ");
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 3);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String generateSentence(String[] str) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str[0]);
    for (String word: str) {
        if (word.equals(".")) {
            builder.append(word);
        } else {
            builder.append(" ").append(word);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: This will create index out of boundary

Comment: I know. You typed faster than me, so I didn't manage to update it in time.

Comment: I remember there is a better way than this. somehow add the space before the token to be added, conditioned on some special character

Comment: What are your scenarios where dot character can appear?

Comment: Just a few punctuation marks that shouldnot have a space before it.

Comment: @user697911 Take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

technically `this is a test .` is correct if your rule is concatenate the strings with a space in between. If you want grammatical symbols like periods and commas to not have a space you would have to do some regex. Also, you don't really need loops or StringBuilders:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "this", "is", "a", "test", "." };
String joined = String.join(" ", array);
joined = joined.replaceAll(" ([.,])", "$1");
```

Something like that, where the first replaceAll() argument is a regex containing all the symbols you care about within the brackets

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expression you can find the punctuation marks and avoid the the last whitespace, for example, if you have the following array:

```
{"this", "is", "a", "test", ".", "and", "this", "is", "another", 
 "test", ";", "here", "is", "one", "test", "more", "!"};
```

So, you can implement of this way:

```
private static String regex = "[.!;?\\-]";

String[] str = {"this", "is", "a", "test", ".", "and", "this", "is",
        "another", "test", ";", "here", "is", "one", "test", "more", "!"};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].matches(regex)) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    }
    sb.append(str[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
this is a test. and this is another test; here is one test more!
```

Answer (score 0):

try this java 8 version:

```
        String[] str = {"this", "is", "a", "test", "."};
    String test = Arrays.stream(str).reduce(new String (), (p,q) -> p+" "+q).replace(" .", ".");
    System.out.println("out ::" + test);
```

output:

> out :: this is a test.